# iOS Daemon app will not start (Jailbreak) - how to debug?

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, daemon, jailbreak

I'm building a daemon app for a jailbroken iPhone and followed the guidelines as described in several questions and answers here on stackoverflow and ofcourse Chris Alvares' webpage at http://chrisalvares.com/blog/38/creating-an-iphone-daemon-part-4/

Xcode and the project are patched by Jailcoder to make it run on my device.

One of the posts on here stated that nowadays it is no longer needed to use the open toolchain template. Uploading the app to the /Applications dir and adding a plist file in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons should be sufficient.

I have performed the above steps but the daemon is not started, or at least not running when i check. In the device logs that are available in Xcode organizer the name of the app or its bundle id are not to be found anywhere. I would at least expect an error with a reason why it won't start.

The contents of the plist file copied to /System/Library/LaunchDaemons:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>dmn.NoUIDaemon.plist</string>
        <key>OnDemand</key>
        <false/>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Applications/NoUIDaemon.app/NoUIDaemon</string>
            <string></string>
            <string></string>
        </array>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/dev/null</string>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Question: is there a way to debug why it won't start the daemon app? Or have i maybe missed a step besides uploading the app to /Applications and adding the plist file to the LaunchDaemons dir ?

**EDIT:**

Contents of my main routine:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Error when launching /Applications/NoUIDaemon.app/NoUIDaemon :

```
R-iPod:/ root# /Applications/NoUIDaemon.app/NoUIDaemon
-sh: /Applications/NoUIDaemon.app/NoUIDaemon: Bad CPU type in executable
```

Note that the app does work without a problem when i run it on my device from Xcode.

Eventhough the daemon cannot be started manually, the answers to Nate's questions:

1) The plist file in LaunchDaemons is indeed named dmn.NoUIDaemon.plist

2) I made the 'mistake' of forgetting the .plist part in the Label contents, so i have tried it with both values, with and without .plist at the end, no difference ofcourse.

3) I have rebooted the device after installing both the app and the plist file using the reboot command

4) I've made sure all the permissions are the same (0775)

5) Will try this when the Bad CPU issue is resolved and it still doesn't work

**FINAL EDIT:**

To hide your Daemon app icon on the springboard, add the following to the Info.plist in your .app:

```
<key>SBAppTags</key>
<array>
    <string>hidden</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Can you login to your device as root via `ssh`, and just execute the command `/Applications/NoUIDameon.app/NoUIDaemon` at the command line?  Does this successfully run your daemon (check to see if it's running with `ps -Aef | grep NoUIDaemon`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said in my comment, first try to make sure your daemon executable is runnable:

1. login to your device as `root`, via `ssh`
2. execute the command `/Applications/NoUIDameon.app/NoUIDaemon` at the command line
3. check to see if it's running with `ps -Aef | grep NoUIDaemon`

**If it's not running**, I would check to make sure that your build process is fake code-signing the `NoUIDaemon` executable.  Jailbroken phones don't require a *valid* signature, but they still do require a signature.  Also, if it doesn't run (or stay running), it might help for you to post the code from your daemon's main program (e.g. main.m):

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   // what's in here?
}
```

**If that does work, and it runs when you start it manually** (but not automatically), then check:

1. is the plist file above named `dmn.NoUIDaemon.plist`?
2. I think this is actually an error in Chris's blog, but the `Label` value in your plist should be `<string>dmn.NoUIDaemon</string>`, not `<string>dmn.NoUIDaemon.plist</string>`.  I don't think this would prevent your daemon from running, I think it's just being consistent with the naming convention of system launch daemons.
3. I don't think just installing the plist file in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` is enough to start the daemon.  You probably need to either reboot the phone, or manually launch the daemon with `launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/dmn.NoUIDaemon.plist`
4. check to make sure the file permissions and ownership of your dmn.NoUIDaemon.plist are the same as the other launch daemon plists in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`.
5. I'm not sure if this is necessary, but I think the name of the daemon (the `Label` and the name of the plist file) are supposed to match the bundle ID specified in your NoUIDaemon-Info.plist file.  So, the Info.plist should have:

```xml
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>NoUIDaemon</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>dmn.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
```

or

```xml
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>NoUIDaemon</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>dmn.NoUIDaemon</string>
```

**Update:**

Also, I don't think your daemon's main program should have a call to `UIApplicationMain`.  It's not supposed to be a UIApplication.  It's supposed to be a background process, right?  If you look [on Page 1 of Chris's blog](http://chrisalvares.com/blog/7/creating-an-iphone-daemon-part-1/), it shows an example.  Here's an example from one of mine:

```objc
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   @autoreleasepool {
      SignalMonitor* daemon = [[SignalMonitor alloc] init];

      // start a timer so that the process does not exit.
      NSTimer* timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: [NSDate date]
                                                interval: 1.0
                                                  target: daemon
                                                selector: @selector(setup:)
                                                userInfo: nil
                                                 repeats: NO];

      NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
      [runLoop addTimer: timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
      [runLoop run];
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Also, here's a copy of my daemon's plist file (Info.plist), with your daemon name in it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>English</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>NoUIDaemon</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>dmn.NoUIDaemon</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>1.0-0</string>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
        <string></string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: R-iPod:/ root# /Applications/NoUIDaemon.app/NoUIDaemon
-sh: /Applications/NoUIDaemon.app/NoUIDaemon: Bad CPU type in executable

Comment: Thats the error i get when executing through ssh. The device is an iPod Touch 4G (i believe that's an arm7 device) and the project is set to arm7 architecture. When i run the app through the debugger it also works fine - i would expect this to fail as well if the 'CPU type is bad'.

Comment: added contents of main routine in my original question

Comment: I have also answered your other questions there, and of course a big thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: @Ronald, ok, so maybe somehow what you're installing on your iPod is the executable built for the **simulator** (Intel architecture).  Can you `cd` to the directory where your `NoUIDaemon` executable is and run `lipo -info NoUIDaemon`?  Lipo will tell you which architectures are present in the executable.  In your case, it should be `armv7`.  (You can also use the `file` command, or `otool -hv` on your executable to get the same info).  Also, see my update above.

Comment: @Ronald, I know you're still stuck on getting the executable to run at all, but I should also mention that the **ownership** on the dmn.NoUIDaemon.plist file should also match the other plists, not just the *permissions*.

Comment: Yes that was indeed the case. The 'file' command returned i386. Having connected my device and selecting build again, i copied the new binary to my device and the same command now returned 'acorn'. Not sure why that's not saying armv7, but checking the running apps after a reboot i can see my UIDaemon running :) Thank you !!

Comment: Thanks also for the snippet of your daemon, will definitely be using that in mine. You think that's the reason iOS shows a visible icon on the springboard for this app? I would expect no icon to show up, just like for instance the SSH daemon.

Comment: @Ronald,  I'm not exactly sure.  All of my daemons have been bundled with a UI Application (so, in my .app folder, there's two executables, the app and the daemon).  It might be using some of the information in the daemon's plist to determine if it should show in SpringBoard.  You can take a look at one of my daemon plists (update above), and experiment.  Clearly, things like icons don't need to be specified in daemon plists.  Try removing everything you don't need.

Comment: It was long time ago thatI saw such a good/interesting question and an excellent answer on StackOverflow. Definitely a +1 for both of you!

Comment: @H2CO3, Thanks.  The credit definitely goes to Chris Alvares.  I've probably referenced this blog post in a dozen different answers.  Hard to find good jailbreak reference material, but that's a great one!

Comment: Thanks for all the help here Nate. Will try to get the icon hidden by experimenting with the Info.plist you posted. If that doesn't work I will post a new question as i understand that is required here. Thanks again :) +1

Comment: for anyone interested in hiding the icon on springboard, see the final edit in my question