# iOS Daemon app will not start (Jailbreak) when Installed it from Cydia

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, daemon, jailbreak

I developed a daemon that is tracking the location as given in the [Chris Alvares](http://chrisalvares.com/blog/38/creating-an-iphone-daemon-part-4/) webpage.

It is working fine if install it through SSH directly to the phone from mac terminal. It's not at all launching if I install the same daemon through Cydia. I am getting the error in the log as

> Mar 3 16:07:11 Jailbreak-iPhone-5S installd[51] : 0×100590000
>   verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for
>   /Applications/Myapp.app/TsavoriteClient: 0xe800801c
>
> Mar 3 16:07:11
>   Jailbreak-iPhone-5S installd[51] : 0×100590000 load_application_info:
>   Failed to validate binary at path /Applications/Myapp.app/Myapp:
>   0xe800801c. This binary may not work properly.

I tried all steps given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345686/ios-daemon-app-will-not-start-jailbreak-how-to-debug).

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: This is not programming question. Try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @lukya its programming only dude. I am clearly asking in the question like is there any extra steps needs to follow to create the build to cydia compare to normal installation through SSH.

Comment: Did you sign your app with `ldid` or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution after long debugging steps!

The problem is with the LaunchDaemon plist file ownership. If I copy plist from SSH the the file properties are as below

> -rw-r--r--  1 root wheel  461 Mar  3 15:20 com.Mycompany.Myapp.plist

If the LaunchDaemons copied by cydia the file properties are as below

> -rw-r--r--  1  503 staff  461 Mar  3 15:20 com.sourcebits.TsavoriteClient.plist

We need to change the LaunchDaemons plist file ownership before preparing the .deb file using the command

```
sudo chown -R root:wheel filePath
```